# How can I change the font-color of a data when it is greater than zero?

Tags: javascript, php, html, css

I want to change the font-color of a data when it is greater than zero. I tried using javascript but it seems like Im doing it wrong. Here's the code

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
             document.getElementsByTagName("h4").style.color = "#ff0000";
    });
</script>
<?php foreach($query as $row):  ?>
<h4 class = "pendingAmount">Pending Amount: ₱<?php echo $pending_total[$row->merge_id]; ?></h4><br>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

Comment: Do you want to change the color of all the text within `<h4>` or just the number? Are you using jQuery?

Comment: @azeós I dont know how to use jquery. I want to change the whole text inside the <h4> tag. Im running foreach to get all the data from the database

Answer (score 2):

```js
var eArr = document.getElementsByClassName("demo")
for(i=0;i<eArr["length"];i++){
  if (eArr[i].innerHTML > 0)
    eArr[i].style.color = "#ff0000";
}
```

```html
<h4 class="demo">3</h4>
<h4 class="demo">0</h4>
<h4 class="demo">-1</h4>
<h4 class="demo">50</h4>
```

Answer (score 0):

Modified that use only php to achieve:

```
<?php foreach($query as $row):  ?>
<h4 class="pendingAmount" <?php if($pending_total[$row->merge_id]>0) echo 'style="color:#ff0000"'; ?>>Pending Amount: ₱<?php echo $pending_total[$row->merge_id]; ?></h4><br>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

Comment: `getElementsByTagName` returns a [`HTMLCollection`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLCollection).

Answer (score 0):

Where is the comparing?

```
document.getElementsByTagName("h4").style.color = "#ff0000";
```

it's wrong! `document.getElementsByTagName` get a object looks like a Array,you should use `document.getElementsByTagName("h4")[index].style.color = "#ff0000";`**index** is a number.

you can try this:

```
$('h4').each(function(){
   $(this).css({'color':'#ff0000'})
})
```

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest giving your h4 an id and then using it to modify the style like this:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  var count = 10;
    if(0 < count) {
      $('.pendingAmount').addClass('colored-pending-amount');
    }
});
```

```html
<style>.colored-pending-amount{color: #ff0000;}</style>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<html>
<body>
<h4 id="pendingAmount" class="pendingAmount">Pending Amount: 10
</h4><br>
</body>
</html>
```

jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/0a4v23pg/7/

The code with php becomes:

```
<style>.colored-pending-amount{color: #ff0000;}</style>
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
             var count = <?php echo $pending_total[$row->merge_id]; ?>;
             $('.pendingAmount').addClass('colored-pending-amount');
    });
</script>
<?php foreach($query as $row):  ?>
<h4 id="pendingAmount class="pendingAmount">Pending Amount: <?php echo $pending_total[$row->merge_id]; ?></h4><br>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

I hope this helps.

Comment: I tried this. But using the same id confuses the script and it only changes the 1st h4 with the id=pendingAmount. Im running a foreach and cant use that.

Comment: IDs are meant to be unique, more than one of the same ID is wrong.

Comment: @Script47 thats true. Thats why im using class to identify the <h4> tag

Comment: @goaty i have modified the code to add a custom class via jquery

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this with or without `javascript`.

**Javascript (jQuery):**

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('.pendingAmount').each(function () {
            var amount = $(this).find('.amount').text();
            if (amount > 0) {
                $(this).css('color', '#f00');
            }
        });
    });
</script>

<?php foreach($query as $row): ?>
    <h4 class="pendingAmount">
        Pending Amount: ₱<span class="amount"><?php echo $pending_total[$row->merge_id]; ?></span>
    </h4>
    <br>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

I added a `<span class="amount"></span>` surrounding the actual amount. With javascript we loop through all `.pendingAmount` elements and check if the `.amount` inside it is greater than 0. If it is, we change the color.

**PHP & CSS:**

```
<style>
    .greater { color: #f00; }
</style>

<?php foreach($query as $row): ?>
    <h4 class="pendingAmount<?php echo ($pending_total[$row->merge_id] > 0) ? ' greater' : '' ?>">
        Pending Amount: ₱<?php echo $pending_total[$row->merge_id]; ?>
    </h4>
    <br>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

In this approach we compare if `$pending_total[$row->merge_id]` is greater than 0 directly with `PHP`. If it is, we add the `greater` class to the `<h4>` which gets styled by `CSS`.